# Issues Converting Dictionary to DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, facebook-marketing-api

I am scraping data from my Facebook Business account and am having issues converting the dictionary I created from the cursor object I got from the FB API connection into a pandas DataFrame. Specifically, using pd.DataFrame(dict) is only returning data from the most recent day of the time series, even though my dict contains the full length of the series.

I have tried different specifications of pd.DataFrame(), but I keep getting the same output.

Obviously I expect pandas to convert the entire dictionary into a df, not just the last chunk... very strange that pd.DataFrame() isn't working for me. Anyone have a solution or has encountered a similar issue before?

```
params = {
    'time_range': {
        'since':  "2019-08-11", 
        'until': "2019-09-09"
        }, 
    'fields': [
        AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id,
        AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.adset_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.spend,
        AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
        AdsInsights.Field.clicks,
        AdsInsights.Field.buying_type,
        AdsInsights.Field.objective,        
        AdsInsights.Field.actions
      ],
    'breakdowns': ['country'],
    'level': 'ad',
    'time_increment': 1
}

#get insights for campaign 
campaign = AdCampaign('act_xxxx')

insights = campaign.get_insights(params=params)
print(insights)

#check that your output is a cursor object
type(insights)

#iterate over cursor object to convert into a dictionary 
for item in insights:
    data = dict(item)
    print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

export_csv = df.to_csv('.../Documents/data.csv', header=True)
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code, and an example dictionary. Are you sure that the dict you're using has information about all of the days?  How did you check?

Comment: I added some code. And yes, I'm very sure that the dictionary I created contains information for the entire series- I looked through it and saw information from each day of the series that specified in 'params'.